# I cant understand this syntax error in AWS lambda, while writing lambda for stopping a ecs task in a service

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

```
 - import json
       import boto3
       
       client = boto3.client('ecs')
       
       def lambda_handler(event, context):
           return {
              response = client.stop_task(
              cluster='newCluster',
              task='d3a857b8f2e1463d85265e08b6dfd9f3',
              reason='none'
                                          )
                   }
```

I have written this lambda, but when I test it , it shows syntax error like below

Response:
{
"errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 8)",
"errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
"stackTrace": [
"  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 8\n           response = client.stop_task(\n"
]
}

Request ID:
"9cb74885-0171-4ed9-9e6f-44e50480139b"

> Function Logs: START RequestId: 9cb74885-0171-4ed9-9e6f-44e50480139b
> Version: $LATEST [ERROR] Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: Syntax error in
> module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 8)
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/task/lambda_function.py" Line 8
>            response = client.stop_task( END RequestId: 9cb74885-0171-4ed9-9e6f-44e50480139b REPORT RequestId:
> 9cb74885-0171-4ed9-9e6f-44e50480139b  Duration: 27.35 ms  Billed
> Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 56 MB  Init
> Duration: 108.01 ms    XRAY TraceId:
> 1-5d846522-6de3bafd93f9f6ddd732c151   SegmentId:
> 5c86ef0b79d59359  Sampled: false

Answer (score 0):

- Worth removing the `response` or return just the response for testing just check by removing it and then tidy up the code later.

```
return {
        client.stop_task(cluster='newCluster',task='d3a857b8f2e1463d85265e08b6dfd9f3',reason='none')
    }
```

- Or worth doing something like this other wise the response is going to be unreachable.

```
response = client.stop_task(
              cluster='newCluster',
              task='d3a857b8f2e1463d85265e08b6dfd9f3',
              reason='none')
return response
```

- Its Worth using the ARN for task and cluster and check how it works [docs attached](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.stop_task)
- This is how i have used it in my working code, reason being optional.(here i have just substituted the values for that variable here for explanation)

```
        client.stop_task(
            cluster='arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:cluster/dev',
            task='arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:task/1de5e17a-422a-4ac4-a493-371970d6d4d6')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
       import boto3

       client = boto3.client('ecs')

       def lambda_handler(event, context):
response=client.stop_task(cluster='newCluster',task='d3a857b8f2e1463d85265e08b6dfd9f3',reason='none')
```

I just removed the return and its braces and it worked.